# Lets Encrypt SSL certificate not working aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, lets-encrypt, amazon-elb, aws-acm

I have successfully generated an lets encrypt ssl certificate for one of my domain. Then I have uploaded the certificate to ACM and then attached to the load balancer. But still the domain is showing as insecure when opened in browser. Please let me know if any other configuration needs to be changed or not.

HTTPS listener is already added to the load balancer and the corresponding ports are open.

I am using nginx

Thank you

Comment: When you view certificate information in your browser, why does it say its insecure?

Comment: jordanm's suggestion is a good one.  Also, try SSL Labs SSL Server Test:  https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/